# Classifying singularities of $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-\sin z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)=\frac{1}{1-\sin z}$
has singularities at $z=\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi n$

but I am not sure how to classify them. The Laurent expansion around $\frac{\pi}{2}$ gives $sin(z-\frac{\pi}{2}) = (z-\frac{\pi}{2})+ \frac{(z-\frac{\pi}{2})^3}{6}$ ... so when I write $\frac{1}{1-\sin z}$ (I think) that seems to suggest a simple pole since $c_{-1}$ nonzero, however, Wolframalpha indicates that it is a pole of order 2.

Comment: Check my answer in your another question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310068/residue-of-fracz2-z1-sinz

Comment: The point is, $f$ is $\frac{1}{1-\sin z}$, not $\frac{1}{\sin z}$.